# Adding a second x-axis (Seaborn)

Tags: python, seaborn, catplot

I want to create a violin plot for my data, which are measurements of cell size.

I have collected my data:

- 3 different time points: 24, 48 and 72h.
- 2 different conditions: untreated and treated.

Now, I want to plot a split violin plot based on a staining I did on my cells, either low or high.

- y-axis: Cell area µm2
- x-axis: Time (24, 48, 72h)
- Condition: untreated, treated.

Each violin plot is split:

- left side: low
- right side: high

Currently, I get this graph:
[result_graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mfwgS.png)

Which has combined the data for 'Condition' as I can't seem to separate the x-axis on *'Time'* and *'Condition'*.

**My Code for the graph:**

```
import seaborn as sns

k = 1
fnt= 8
plt.clf()
sns.set_context('paper')
sns.set(font_scale=1.5)
sns.set_style('ticks')
plt.figure(0,(4,5),dpi=300)

plt.title('Cell size after NCS treatment')

custom_palette = {'CDK low': '#a6dba0', 'CDK high': '#008837'}

ax = sns.violinplot(data=tidy_df,x='Time',y='value',hue='CDK status', 
               order=plot_order,
               hue_order=['CDK low', 'CDK high'],
               split=True,gap=0,
               palette=custom_palette,
               alpha=0.9,
               linewidth=0.5,
               edgecolor='black',
               inner='quartile',
               width=0.8,
               dodge=True
               )
```

I tried to generate the plot using catplot `kind=violin`
but this did not work either, because I could only separate it by making two separate graphs using `col='Condition'`

Can I somehow separate the Time and Condition on the x-axis?

Comment: You could create an extra column that combines Time and Condition.  And then use that new column as `x`. Alternatively, you can stay with the 2 subplots of the catplot, but remove the spacing and the y-axis of the second plot, making it appear as one plot.